# Search and print list of the any number in the pdf document between "[" "]"

Tags: pdf, search, numbers

I have PDF document, with information. I need only the number between [] in the document. For instance, [12223-23-56], print as 12223-23-56

Answer (score 0):

In windows that's a one line command with `xpdf pdftotext` or use poppler utils but that is more than one.exe and you will need to modify the simple code you use to remove ends of strings.

`pdftotext -layout "numbers in brackets text.pdf" text.txt & findstr /r [[0-9]] text.txt`

[image]

if you only want those with - then filter first

```
>pdftotext -layout "numbers in brackets text.pdf" text.txt & findstr /r [[0-9]] text.txt|find "-"
[1-2-3]
[12223-23-56]
```

etc. but I have given enough hints to use in your required minimal attempt.